# TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) on <Redirect to="/profile"/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question about an error that regards a redirect to another page when a user was logged.

Everything is fine until the user logs in perfectly and enters the "/ profile" page, but if I then wanted to redirect the URL "/ home" an error is generated: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol ( Symbol.iterator)).

This error, however, obviously disappears if I refresh the URL "/ profile"

this is my example code that return the error:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import AuthService from "./services/auth.service";
import Profile from "./components/profile_component/profile.component";
import BoardTeacher from "./components/boards_component/board-moderator.component";
import BoardStudent from "./components/boards_component/board-user.component";
import LoginPage from "./pages/login/login.page";
import RegistrationPage from "./pages/registration/registration.page";
import FormsPage from "./pages/registration_form/registration_forms.page";
import Settings from "./components/UI_components/settings_component/settings.component";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      showBoard: undefined,
      currentUser: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    console.log(user)
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user, 
        showBoard: user.roles.includes("ROLE_STUDENT") ? BoardStudent : BoardTeacher,
      });
    }
  }

  logOut() {
    AuthService.logout();
  }

  render() {
    let { currentUser, showBoard } = this.state;

    console.log(currentUser)

    return (
      <div className="main-site-container">
        <Settings/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]}>
            {currentUser  ? <Redirect to="/profile" /> : <LoginPage/>}
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}>
              {currentUser ? <Redirect to="/profile" /> :  <LoginPage/>}
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationPage} />
          <Route exact path="/register/form" component={FormsPage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/user" component={showBoard} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you must be using `.map()` wrongly at `Profile` component

Comment: `<Redirect to="/page"/>` code is not present her, provide full code to understand problem

Comment: @AshishKamble sorry for `<Redirect to="/page"/> `I refer to `<Redirect to="/profile"/>`